# VB.NET - Reading encrypted data in a TXT file line by line

Tags: vb.net

I have found this code to encrypt/decrypt data in VB.NET:

```
    Dim cypherTextBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData)
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(cypherTextBytes)
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, Me.decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    Dim plainTextBytes(cypherTextBytes.Length) As Byte
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()
```

The problem that I am having is that I don't know how to read a .TXT file line by line, saving one line at a time as "encryptedData", and decrypting it, adding it to a line in another .TXT document.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt the data one line at a time?  Line breaks in text are just characters like any other.  When you encrypt text you convert the entire text to bytes and then you encrypt those bytes.  When you decrypt, you decrypt all the data and then you convert the resultant bytes into text.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will return an `IEnumerable(Of String)` containing the lines in the file. Then simply loop through those lines and pass each line as the `encryptedData` value.

Inside this loop, once you have decrypted the line you could append the result to another file using the [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This method takes an array of lines to be appended so in your case you could simply pass it an array with 1 element.

Further improvement to your code would be to extract the decryption snippet into a separate method that will take 1 parameter representing the encrypted data and returning the decrypted data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able to get this code: https://pastebin.com/kLnTrd4G, but I get a "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'ReadLinesIterator' to type 'String' is not valid.' error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks again.